# cfitsio: help installation

Tags: macos

Hi I'm trying to install the cfitsio library on my mac osx 10.8. Following the instruction on the readme file, after having untar the tar file, changed directory to cfitsio and export with this command (I use bash)

```
export CFLAGS="-arch ppc -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -O2"
```

if I put in the command line:

```
./configure
```

I get this erros:

```
checking for uname... 1
checking for gcc... cc
checking for C compiler default output file name... configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details.
```

I have also installed Xcode developers tools.

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 1):

You may or may not have a compiler for PPC? Do you need a universal library for non-Intel? I'd try:

```
export CFLAGS="-arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -O2"
```

Then run `./configure`.

Refer to the following post regarding command-line tool install with Xcode: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329243/xcode-4-4-command-line-tools

Answer (score 0):

The explanation seems to be for an older Xcode or something. This is what worked for me - instead of exporting the `CFLAGS` in the environment, pass it directly to the configure as follows:

`./configure <other options> CFLAGS="-arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -02"`